# How to get current position of animating uiview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, position, cabasicanimation

I want current position of animating UIView during animation and I am using this code.

```
CABasicAnimation * m_pAnimationObj = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation"];
[m_pAnimationObj setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0,-50)]];
[m_pAnimationObj setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height+100)]];
m_pAnimationObj.duration = 2.0;
m_pAnimationObj.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[DropImage.layer addAnimation:m_pAnimationObj forKey:@"animations"];
```

Please answer if anyone knows about this.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
CGRect currentCenter = [drawingView.layer.presentationLayer center];
```

or

```
CGRect currentFrame = [DropImage.layer.presentationLayer frame];
```